# Trouble in installing WxWidgets

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, wxwidgets

When i trying to install wxwidgets i getting this error message:

[image: Error message]

What should I do?

Comment: You are missing a space between `-MT` and the following object file.

Comment: Also, since your compiler doesn't understand `-MP` my guess is it is too old a version to compile wxwidgets.

Comment: example pls what i should write in cmd

Comment: i downloaded  tdm64-gcc-5.1.0-2 it latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some other `gcc` in your path, the normal one definitely understands all of these options and, contrary to a comment above, no space is needed after `-MT`. Try running `where gcc` to find out where is it coming from and set up your `PATH` to exclude it.

FWIW I've just tried building wxWidgets with TDM 5.1.0 and it worked without any problems.

Comment: what means "You have some other gcc in your path"?

Comment: You have another version of the compiler in one of the directories in your `PATH` environment variable. An even simpler way to verify if this is the case is to simply run `gcc --version`.

Comment: I wrote these commands:
cd %WXWIN%\build\msw
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc clean
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 UNICODE=1 WXUNIV=0
and in end command i get error such as screenshot

Comment: 2.95 but why i dont know?!

Comment: C:\FPC\2.4.2\bin\i386-Win32\gcc.exe
C:\TDM-GCC-32\bin\gcc.exe

Comment: merci, france guy, i remove C:\FPC\2.4.2\bin\i386-Win32\gcc.exe and all work great, big thanks

Comment: You should open another question for a different topic and please don't post screenshot when copying-and-pasting text is so much simpler both to post and to read.

Answer (score -2):

**The Problem is that some files from your compiler are missing**
Solution:
Try reinstalling you Compiler. If you are using CodeBlocks, reinstall it because it contains compiler with its installer.