# Trouble with installing wxwidgets 2

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, wxwidgets

If you saw my [trouble with installing wxwidgets 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856626/trouble-in-installing-wxwidgets) and if you too get problems again u must look this question and read answers
Lets begin, after deleting useless gcc path i got this in console:

```
from ../../src/common/any.cpp:18:
C:/TDM-GCC-32/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error
: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 st
andard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -st
d=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
  ^
In file included from ..\..\include/wx/string.h:46:0,
                 from ..\..\include/wx/any.h:19,
                 from ../../src/common/any.cpp:18:
..\..\include/wx/strvararg.h:350:18: error: 'is_enum' in namespace 'std' does no
t name a template type
     typedef std::is_enum<T> is_enum;
                  ^
..\..\include/wx/strvararg.h:354:54: error: 'is_enum' was not declared in this s
cope
     enum { value = wxFormatStringSpecifierNonPodType<is_enum::value>::value };
                                                      ^
..\..\include/wx/strvararg.h:354:68: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     enum { value = wxFormatStringSpecifierNonPodType<is_enum::value>::value };
                                                                    ^
makefile.gcc:11712: recipe for target 'gcc_mswud\baselib_any.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswud\baselib_any.o] Error 1

C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\build\msw>
```

It was command

```
cd %WXWIN%\build\msw
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc clean
>>>mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 UNICODE=1 WXUNIV=0<<<
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 UNICODE=1 WXUNIV=0
```

Comment: It's explicitly telling you the error.  On the third line of you output it says your compiler doesn't support C++ 2011.  Either enable that support or upgrade your compiler.

Comment: How to run support c++ 2011?

Comment: The error message is telling you how to enable it.  It may look like gibberish but you should read compiler warning and errors very carefully.

Comment: i dont understand what i must do, i see this **-std=gnu++11** and what next?

Comment: You have to add that option when you invoke the compiler when you compile your project.  You will have to look into your `makefile` to see where the compiler options are set.

Comment: where these options? where i must look? i dont understand

Comment: Please reread my comment.  I told you exactly where to find them.

Comment: i reread and maybe i am idiot but i dont understand what i must do

Comment: what i must write in cmd?

Comment: i invoke this command:`mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=0 UNICODE=1 WXUNIV=0` how i must modify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately wxWidgets 3.0.2 had been released before g++ 5.1 (and even before, or maybe close to, g++ 4.9), so it doesn't compile out of the box with it in C++98 mode when using it. This problem has been fixed since, but not in an official release, so you have 2 choices:

1. Apply [this fix](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/commit/2632977f6b6aa2f5c6254a69936ca288ace0560d) to your sources. If you're unsure how to do it, your best bet is to just grab the latest sources from `WX_3_0_BRANCH` from git.
2. Build in C++11 mode by appending `CXXFLAGS=-std=gnu++11` to your make command line. If you do this, remember to use the same flags when building your application using wxWidgets too later!